# System.Web.Optimization changes order of js files when minifying javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net-4.5, bundling-and-minification

I am observing a very peculiar behaviour when minifying files with `System.Web.Optimization`, I am already using `IBundleOrderer` that works fine in preserving file order when I am not minifying the files

```
public class RespectGivenBundleOrder : IBundleOrderer
{
    public IEnumerable<BundleFile> OrderFiles(BundleContext context, IEnumerable<BundleFile> files)
    {
        return files;
    }
}

public static void RegisterTestingBundle(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        var bundle = new ScriptBundle("~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/bundles/Testing");
        bundle.Orderer = new RespectGivenBundleOrder();
        bundle.Include(
            string.Format("{0}jquery-{{version}}.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}ua-parser.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}OnTheMove_Core.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}OnTheMove_TheApplication.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}OnTheMove_JQMQueryString.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}OnTheMove_OfflineAuditing.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}OnTheMove_DatabaseManager.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}OnTheMove.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}OnTheMove_Offline.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}OnTheMove_DatabaseLoader.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}OnTheMove_DatabaseTestHelper.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}OnTheMove_SmartScriptPlayer.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}jasmine.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}jasmine-html.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}jasmine-jquery-{{version}}.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}jasmine-OnTheMove-GenericMocksAndHelpers.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}jasmine-OnTheMove-DatabaseManager-SiebelToSQL-Tests.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}jasmine-OnTheMove-TreeValidator-Tests.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}jasmine-OnTheMove-GlobalFunction-Tests.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}jasmine-OnTheMove-OnTheMove_BusinessComponent-Tests.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}jasmine-OnTheMove_DatabaseTestHelper-Tests.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}jasmine-OnTheMove_OfflineAuditing-Tests.js", baseJSFolder),
            string.Format("{0}jasmine-OnTheMove-JQueryExtension-Tests.js", baseJSFolder));
        bundles.Add(bundle);
    }
```

but when I do turn the minification on I am getting javascript errors and by inspecting the beginning of minified file in chrome developer tools I can immediately see that order is messed up.

In immediate window when I execute `var cont = new BundleResolver(BundleTable.Bundles ).GetBundleContents("~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/bundles/Testing")`  I get

```
Count = 23
    [0]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/jquery-1.7.1.js"
    [1]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/ua-parser.js"
    [2]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/OnTheMove_Core.js"
    [3]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/OnTheMove_TheApplication.js"
    [4]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/OnTheMove_JQMQueryString.js"
    [5]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/OnTheMove_OfflineAuditing.js"
    [6]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/OnTheMove_DatabaseManager.js"
    [7]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/OnTheMove.js"
    [8]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/OnTheMove_Offline.js"
    [9]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/OnTheMove_DatabaseLoader.js"
    [10]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/OnTheMove_DatabaseTestHelper.js"
    [11]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/OnTheMove_SmartScriptPlayer.js"
    [12]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/jasmine.js"
    [13]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/jasmine-html.js"
    [14]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/jasmine-jquery-1.7.0.js"
    [15]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/jasmine-OnTheMove-GenericMocksAndHelpers.js"
    [16]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/jasmine-OnTheMove-DatabaseManager-SiebelToSQL-Tests.js"
    [17]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/jasmine-OnTheMove-TreeValidator-Tests.js"
    [18]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/jasmine-OnTheMove-GlobalFunction-Tests.js"
    [19]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/jasmine-OnTheMove-OnTheMove_BusinessComponent-Tests.js"
    [20]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/jasmine-OnTheMove_DatabaseTestHelper-Tests.js"
    [21]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/jasmine-OnTheMove_OfflineAuditing-Tests.js"
    [22]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/jasmine-OnTheMove-JQueryExtension-Tests.js"
```

which shows that order is being preserved, however when I minify it on the fly (`var contents =BundleManager.GetBundleContents("~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/bundles/Testing");`) I get

```
"function TheApplication(){return window.onTheMove.theApplication}function decodeQueryString(n,t,i,r){var f,u={},s,h,e,o;if(i||(i=function(){return}),...
```

Which is beginning of  `OnTheMove_TheApplication.js` and not `jquery-1.7.1.js` that I am expecting. One solution I see is to split it apart into more bundles and try to handle it that way.
 **Why minifier is not preserving order? Is my expectation wrong?**

Comment: Just for fun, try an experiment by changing your orderer to return the files alphabetically? Let us know what that does.

Comment: @Haney when changing the orderer to `files.OrderBy(o => o.IncludedVirtualPath);` minification result comes out as  `"function decodeQueryString(n,t,i,r){var f,u={},s,h,e,o;if(i||(i=function(){return}),r&&(u=r),t.length>1&&t[t...` which is line 17 of `OnTheMove.js` and `new BundleResolver(BundleTable.Bundles ).GetBundleContents ("~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/bundles/Testing");` starts with `[0]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/jasmine.js"
    [1]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/jasmine-html.js"` and `[12]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/OnTheMove.js"` is 13th item in the list.

Comment: So it clearly is not respecting your order. How strange.

Comment: This is odd, but try moving the set of the orderer to AFTER including the scripts?

Comment: Also try a single Include of basefolder/*.js and see what that does

Comment: @Haney same outcome `"function TheApplication(){return window.onTheMove.theApplication}functi`

Comment: under initial inspection works fine  `var bundle = new ScriptBundle("~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/bundles/Testing");
            bundle.Orderer = new RespectGivenBundleOrder();
            bundle.IncludeDirectory(baseJSFolder, "*.js");` then `new BundleResolver(BundleTable.Bundles ).GetBundleContents ("~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/bundles/Testing");
Count = 47
    [0]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/Configurator.js"
` and `BundleManager.GetBundleContents("~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/bundles/Testing");
"function runXML(){var n=$(\".WS_text\").last().val();doWSCall(\"/ea..` which is line 10 of `Configurator.js`

Comment: @Haney I am taking my words back :) don't think it does - 1st file is ok but then second seems to be `OnTheMove.js` and not `fullcalendar.js` as in list `[0]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/Configurator.js"
    [1]: "~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js/fullcalendar.min.js"` not 100% certain, it's kinda hard to read minified js from output window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59739/discussion-between-haney-and-liufa).

Comment: What do you mean "when I minify it on the fly". You can set `EnableOptimizations = true/false` to control whether or not bundling occurs...  You are calling the bundle two different ways and getting two different results. What happens if you try the regular `@Scripts.Render("~/OnTheMoveWebFiles/bundles/Testing")` to get the bundle?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev `minify it on the fly` I mean putting a breakpoint and coding into Immediate window. When not minifying order is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed solving this issue by creating an extension :

```
public class AsIsBundleOrderer : IBundleOrderer
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<FileInfo> OrderFiles(BundleContext context, IEnumerable<FileInfo> files)
    {
        return files;
    }
}

internal static class BundleExtensions
{
    public static Bundle ForceOrdered(this Bundle sb)
    {
        sb.Orderer = new AsIsBundleOrderer();
        return sb;
    }
}
```

Then, you can register your bundle

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/home")
            .Include("~/Scripts/leaflet-0.6.4.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/oms.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/home.js").ForceOrdered()

        );
```