# .NET core BundlerMinifier wrong order of files

Tags: c#, .net-core, bundling-and-minification

I am using BundlerMinifier for .NET core 2.1 but i cannot set correct order of bundling files.

I have following files in `wwwroot/js/Lib/`:

```
1.jquery.min.js
2.jquery.ui.min.js
3.server.js
```

After bundling this files are sorted within a site.js file in specified order:

```
2.jquery.ui.min.js
3.server.js
1.jquery.min.js
```

Page do not load because jquery ui is loaded before jquery. 
I have not found any solution in documentation. Am I missing something?

This is my bundleconfig.json file:

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site-lib.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/Lib/"
    ],
    // Optionally specify minification options
    "minify": {
      "enabled": false,
      "renameLocals": true
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428952/system-web-optimization-changes-order-of-js-files-when-minifying-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem regarding the BundlerMinifier and the order it was reading the files. My solution was to remove the old bundle.js and bundleconfig.json and rebundle everything. What I did differently was that I excluded (in my case jquery-3.3.1.js) from the bundle and bundled everyhing else. After that I first included the jQuery-3.3.1.js and after that the bundle.js.

```
<script src="~/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script
<script src="~/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps :)